# Android 4.1 web browser, Vimeo videos, and the Froogaloop API, Issue?

Tags: android, vimeo

So I am having issues with the Vimeo player on an Android device (Samsung Galaxy S3) running Android 4.1.
In the web browser it seems that the Android OS web browser turns the iFrame into a native HTML5 player once the video starts.  This seems to render the Froogaloop API useless.
An example can be seen here: http://www.dmns.org/science/museum-scientists/chip-colwell-chanthaphonh/mobile .
Click on the 'Videos' tab and click on the Next and Previous arrows.  The arrows should stop the videos.
Those should 'unload' or stop/pause the video but they does not. It works on desktops fine and older Android devices, but the new Android 4.1 OS the player does not stop when the arrows are selected.
Note:  I have not downloaded Flash for Android and don't want to.

If you have a solution or any suggestions to try that would help tremendously. Thanks in advance.